# Not able to create PostgreSQL file using Osm2po?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, osm2po

I am new to the GIS community.

After downloading the osm2po jar file, I have run following the instructions from [underdark](https://anitagraser.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/) tutorial. Also, from Carsten's answer in gis stack exchange, I have enabled instructions in osm2po.config file but the sql file is not generated in the prefix folder.

I did not get any error while starting the web server.

Answer (score 1):

I have uncommented the following line which redirects the sql to stdout;

#postp.pipeOut = true

Now the issue resolved after I commented the line or can make the parameter to false.